# with Google Container Engine, how to create a cluster with more than 3 nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

If I start a [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) cluster like this:

```
gcloud container clusters --zone=$ZONE create $CLUSTER_NAME
```

I get three worker nodes.  How can I create a cluster with more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to create a different number of worker nodes by using the `--num-nodes` option when you create the cluster, like this:

```
gcloud container clusters --zone=$ZONE create $CLUSTER_NAME --num-nodes=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Config the zone

```
gcloud config set compute/zoe us-central1-a
```

Step 2: config the region

```
gcloud config set compute /region us-central1
```

Step 3: create cluster specifying the number of nodes

```
gcloud container clusters create [$Cluster_name] –num-node=4
```

Answer (score 0):

By default gke creates 3 nodes , 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB memory.You will get these specs with this command

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster_name --zone=zone_name
```

but you can specify number of nodes and select the appropriate plan for your cluster with these params

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster_name --zone=zone_name --num-nodes=no_of_nodes --min-cpu-platform=cpu_platform_name
```

visit https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform to know more about it.